# Sort by date Objects read from CSV

Tags: java, list, date, sorting, object

I am reading a CSV file and I am converting each row into an object of Type Obj, here is my Obj class below. The problem is that I would like to sort my ObjList based on the date attribute but this does not work. I am using this code to sort my list but it's not working, how can I fix this?

```
List<Obj> sorted = objList.stream().sorted(
                (a,b)->
        {
        
                return a.getDate().compareTo(b.getDate());
            
        }
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The whole Obj class:

```
package yas;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import yas.SimpleTesing.DateItem;

public class Obj{
        String law=""; 
        String school=""; 
        public Date date=null; 
        
        public Date getDate() {
            return date;
        }
        public void setDate(Date date) {
            this.date = date;
        }
        Calendar cal= null; 
        public Obj() {
            
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Obj [law=" + law + ", school=" + school + ", Calendatr=" + cal + "]";
        }
        
        
        
    }
```

Here is the file doing the reading process
package yas;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import yas.SimpleTesing.SortByDate;

public class main {
     static List<Obj> objList= new ArrayList<Obj>(); 
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        InputStream inputStream = null;
         String file ="C:\\Users\\mouh\\eclipse-workspace\\yas\\src\\yas\\masters";
         
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String currentLine = reader.readLine();
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/M/yyyy");
        
         String date = sdf.format(new Date());
         while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {

               
                
                if(currentLine.contains("/")){
                     Obj obj = new Obj(); 
                    System.out.println(currentLine);
                    String[] elems = currentLine.split(","); 
                    obj.law=elems[0]; 
                    obj.school=elems[1];
                    Date mydate = sdf.parse(elems[2]);

                    obj.date=mydate; 
                    Calendar myCal = new GregorianCalendar();
                    myCal.setTime(mydate);
                    obj.cal=myCal; 
                    objList.add(obj); 


                }
         }
         
         
         
         
//       System.out.println(currentLine);
         reader.close();
         
         
          List<Obj> sorted = objList.stream().sorted(
                (a,b)->
        {
           
                return a.getDate().compareTo(b.getDate());
            
        }
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());
     

     
     // sotrted 
     for(Obj obj: sorted) {
         System.out.println(obj.toString()); 
     }
         
        
       

    }

    
    
}
```

Here is my CSV file masters:

```
DROIT PÉNAL,a,date
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Université de Grenoble,4/4/2022
M1 Droit pénal fondamental,Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Université Paris 1 Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Université Toulouse Capitole,
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles parcours criminologie,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles parcours droit pénal et sciences pénales,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Criminologie,Faculté de Bordeaux,21/3/2022
Droti de l'execution des peines et droits de l'homme,Faculté de bordeaux,21/3/2022
Droit pénal et carrières judiciaires,Faculté de Nantes,21/3/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Faculté de Montpellier,19/5/2022
Criminologie,Faculté de Bordeaux,21/3/2022
Criminologie et victimologie,Faculté de Poitiers,9/5/2022
Droit pénal approfondi,Faculté de Bordeaux,21/3/2022
M2 Droit et justice pénale,Faculté de Poitiers,9/5/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Université de Nancy,17/6/2022
Droit pénal des affaires publiques et privée,Faculte de Toulouse Capitole,1/5/2022
Droit pénal européen et international,Faculté de Bordeaux,21/3/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles programme franco-québécois,Faculté de Toulouse,
Criminologie,Faculté de Strasbourg,27/5/2022
Sciences sociales et criminologie,Faculté de Nantes,21/3/2022
Droit pénal appliqué,Faculté de Strasbourg,27/5/2022
Pratique du droit pénal des affaires,UPEC,3/6/2022
Pénologie,Unviersité Lyon III,10/5/2022
Droit pénal fondamental,Unviersité Lyon III,10/5/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Université de Clermont Auvergne,
M1 droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Faculté de Lille,
Droit pénal et judiciaire,Université de Reims Champagne-Ardenne,20/5/2022
"Droit pénal traitement criminologique et psychologie forensique",Université de Reims Champagne-Ardenne,20/5/2022
Droit pénal,Université de Reims Champagne-Ardenne,20/5/2022
Droit pénal fondamental et comparé franco-allemand,Faculté de Strasbourg,27/5/2022
Droit pénal,Université de Picardie Jules-Verne,
Droit pénal économique et de la conformité,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Droit pénal et politiques criminelles,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Droit pénal international comparé,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Droit pénal comparé,Université de Bordeaux,23/3/2022
Droit pénal et sciences criminelles,Université de Pau et des pays de l'Adour,
M2 Criminologie,Panthéon-Assas,
M2 Justice Pénale internationale,Panthéon-Assas,
M2 Droit pénal et sciences pénales,Panthéon-Assas,
Sciences criminologiques (M2),Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
M2 Lutte contre la criminalité finanière et organisée,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
M2 Droit de l'execution des peines,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
M2 Sciences pénales,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
M2 Droit de l'execution des peines,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
M2 Droit pénal et international des affaires,Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
M2 Criminologie,Faculté de Bordeaux,13/5/2022
M2 Droit pénal approfondi,Université de Lorraine,
M2 Etudes pénales et criminelles,Faculté de Lille,
M2 Justice pénale internationale,Faculté de Lille,
,,
SÉCURITÉ ET DÉFENSE,,
Sécurité internationale et défense,Unviersité Lyon III,
Droit public parcours sécurité et défense,Panthéon-Assas,
"Sécurité internationale cyber-sécurité et défense",Université de Grenoble,4/4/2022
Droit er administration de la défense,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Droit public parcours sécurité intérieure,Université de Nice,20/5/2022
Sécurité Intérieure,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Sécurité intérieure,Unviersité Lyon III,10/5/2022
"M2 Sécurité internationale défense et intelligence économique",Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Sécurité intérieure,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
,,
DROIT SOCIAL,,
Droit social,Paris-Saclay,15/6/2022
Droit social,UPEC,
Droit social général,Panthéon-Assas,
Protection sociale et rémunération (alternance),Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit et pratiques des relations de travail (DPRT) (alternance),Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit du travail,Université de Reims Champagne-Ardenne,20/5/2022
Droit social et de la santé,Université de Nantes,21/3/2022
Droit social,Faculté d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Droit social,Université de Rennes,
Droit social,Université de Bordeaux,18/3/2022
Droit social,Université de Strasbourg,
Droit social,Université de Montpellier,
Droit social,Université de Clermont Auvergne,14/5/2022
Droit social,Unviersité Lyon III,
Droit social,Université de Toulon,9/5/2022
Droit social,Université de Nanterre,
Droit social,Université de Cergy-Pontoise,
Droit et gestion des personnes du secteur sanitaire et social,Université de Toulon,9/5/2022
Droit de la protection sociale d'entreprise,Panthéon-Sorbonne,
Droit du travail et de la protection sociale,Faculté de Bordeaux,18/3/2022
Droit social et relations sociales dans l'entreprise,Faculté de Sorbonne Paris-Nord,
Relations professionnelles,Faculté de Nanterre,
Gestion des ressources humaines - stage,Faculté de Nanterre,
Gestion des ressources humaines - contrat d'apprentissage et de professionnalisation,Faculté de Nanterre,
Droit social - analyse et pratique,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Protection sociale et santé - stage,Faculté de Nanterre,
Protection sociale et santé - apprentissage,Faculté de Nanterre,
Protection sociale et santé - recherche,Faculté de Nanterre,
"Droit social interne, européen et international",Faculté de Strasbourg,
Master droit et management social de l'entreprise,Faculté de Toulouse,
"Master droit du travail,emploi et protection sociale",Faculté de Toulouse,
Droit social,Faculté de Nancy,17/5/2022
Master droit social et gestion des ressources humaines,Université d'Orléans,
Droit social,Faculté d'Amiens,
Droit social franco-italien,Université de Cergy-Pontoise,
Droit social comparé,Université de Bordeaux,23/3/2022
Droit et sciences du travail européen,Faculté de Toulouse,
Droit de la protection sociale d'entreprise,Ecole de droit de la Sorbonne,
Droit social et relations sociales dans l'entreprise,Paris 13-Descartes,10/5/2022
Droit social et de la santé,Faculté de Nantes,21/3/2022
Droit social et ressources humaines,Faculté de Mulhouse,
Droit du travail et de l'emploi et de la protection sociale,Faculté de Toulouse,
Analyse et pratique,Faculté de Nanterre,
,,
M2 Droit social approfondi,Faculté de Nantes,18/3/2022
Droit social et management des ressources humaines M2,Faculté de Nantes,
Droit de l'entreprise,Université de Pau et des pays de l'Adour,
Management et administration des entreprises,Université de Pau et des pays de l'Adour,
Management sectoriel,Université de Pau et des pays de l'Adour,
,,
,,
DROIT DES AFFAIRES,,
Droit des affaires approfondi,Unviersité Lyon III,10/5/2022
Restructuration et traitement des entreprises en difficulté,Unviersité Lyon III,
Ethique et droit des affaires,Faculté de Cergy-Pontoise,11/5/2022
Droit des affaires,Sorbonne-Paris nord,
Droit des affaires,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires et droit fiscal - spécialité droit des affaires et fiscalité,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires et droit fiscal - spécialité droit fiscal,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires et droit fiscal - spécialité fiscalité internationale,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires et économie,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires et management / MBA,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires internationales,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit européen des affaires et de la concurrence,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit privé et public des affaires (réservé aux sportifs de haut niveau),Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires parcours juriste d'affaires,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires parcours techniques de restructuration des entreprises en difficulté,Panthéon-Assas,9/5/2022
M2 Droit des affaires et économie,Panthéon-Assas,
Droit des affaires,Paris-saclay,14/6/2022
Droit des affaires,Universite de Cote d'Azur,
Droit des affaires,Université de Nantes,21/3/2022
Droit des affaires,Université de Lorraine,
Droit des affaires,Université de Poitiers,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires,Faculté de Rennes,
Droit des affaires,Université d'Angers,13/5/2022
Droit des affaires et fiscalité,Paris Dauphine,1/6/2022
Droit des affaires,Université Lumière Lyon II,
Droit des affaires parcours juriste d'affaires,Université Paris Descartes,
Droit des affaires parcours juriste d'affaires européen,Université Paris Descartes,
Droit des affaires parcours juristes d'affaires international,Université Paris Descartes,
Droit des affaires parcours juriste d'affaires fiscalites,Université Paris Descartes,
"Droit des affaires parcours banque et finance, droit et régulation du système bancaire",Université Paris Descartes,
Parcours Banking et Finance (Abu Dhabi ),Université Paris Descartes,
Droit des affaires parcours affaires santé,Faculté de Saint-Etienne,8/4/2022
Droit des affaires parcours droit et entreprise / juriste d'affaires,Faculté de Saint-Etienne,8/4/2022
Droit des affaires parcours RH de l'entreprise et droit social,Faculté de Saint-Etienne,8/4/2022
Contentieux des affaires,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Droit fondamental de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Droit des structures et des activités de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Droit fiscal de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Administration et liquidation des entreprises en difficulté,Université d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Droit des affaires,Université d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Droit fiscal,Université d'Aix-Marseille,9/5/2022
Juriste européen des affaires,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Analyse et pratique du droit des affaires (apprentissage),Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Gestion juridique de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,7/6/2022
Analyse et pratique du droit des affaires (apprentissage),Faculté de Nanterre,28/4/2022
Contentieux des affaires,Faculté de Nanterre,28/4/2022
Droit des structures et des activités de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,28/4/2022
Droit fondamental de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,28/4/2022
Droit fiscal de l'entreprise,Faculté de Nanterre,28/4/2022
Juriste européen des affaires,Faculté de Nanterre,28/4/2022
Administration et liquidations d'entreprises en difficultés,Faculté Toulouse,
double master Droit et gestion des entreprises / Droit des affaires,Université de Toulouse 1 Capitole,15/4/2022
Droit des affaires,Université de Reims Champagne-Ardenne,
Administration et liquidation d'entreprises en difficulté (Apprentissage),Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Droit de l'entreprise,Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Droit des affaires,Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Droit fiscal,Panthéon-Sorbonne,7/6/2022
Droit international des affaires,Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Droit des affaires parcours HEC,Panthéon-Sorbonne,22/4/2022
Droit bancaire et financier,Panthéon-Sorbonne,3/4/2022
Contrats et contentieux d'affaires,Université de Caen,25/5/2022
Juriste conseil d'entreprise,Université de Caen,25/5/2022
Droit des affaires comparé,Université de Bordeaux,23/3/2022
Droit des affaires,Université Grenoble Alpes,
Droit des affaires et fiscalité,Université d'Orléans,
Droit et régulation du système économique,Paris Descartes,14/6/2022
Juriste d'affaires,Paris Descartes,12/6/2022
Juriste d'affaires européen,Paris Descartes,14/6/2022
Juriste d'affaires international,Paris Descartes,14/6/2022
Juriste fiscaliste,Paris Descartes,14/6/2022
Droit des affaires,Université de Nancy,17/6/2022
Droit fiscal des affaires,Université de Lille,
Droit des affaires,Université Côte d'Azur,20/5/2022
M2 Droit bancaire et fintech,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Droit algorithmique et gouvernance des données,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Droit de la propriété intellectuelle et des nouvelles technologies,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Droit économique,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Juriste d'affaires,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Juriste des risques et du développement durable,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
M2 Juriste du sport,Université Côte d'Azur,10/6/2022
```

Comment: Are you using Java 8  or higher? Is there a reason why you still using `Date` instead of `LocalDate` from the `java.time` API?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the last in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: *they say that the Date comparator is deprecated* Which comparator? I don’t see any in your code?

Comment: I updated my description, I tried some different code and it does not return the list sorted

Comment: I executed the code in my machine looks good to me, where do you have the issue?

Comment: no issue I fixed it on my own

Comment: Good to read, glad on your behalf. Please delete the question if you don’t need it. (Or if you think your solution will be useful for others, post it as an answer to your own question.)